# SQL Server - BIT data type Issue

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have a table in my SQL Server 2012 as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(100),STATUS BIT);
```

I inserted the data like this, by mistake,

```
INSERT INTO TEST SELECT 1,'A',2;
```

When I queried the result, I found the column "STATUS" storing "1". Whatever value I insert instead of "0", it stores "1". I felt if I define a column as BIT then it should not allow inserting any value apart from 0 and 1.

Is there any trace flag that restricts such insertion? I'm using SQL Server 2012 SP3 now.

Comment: What do you mean "whatever value I insert"? an example value please?

Comment: I meant anything apart from "0". I gave an example "2" in my question.

Comment: That is because a Bit can only accept 0 or 1, this data type is used as a boolean for true and false.

Comment: Yes, this is the [documented behaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177603.aspx): "Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1."

Comment: Simply no. Because `2` is a `INT`. Just check about implicit conversion for bits columns.

Comment: The problem is the implicit conversion. Just use parametrized queries with explicit data types, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Lets face it, Microsoft SHOULD raise a warning (if ANSI_WARNINGS ON) whenever there is an attempt to store a non NULL, ZERO or ONE value on a BIT column or variable, instead of keeping this non-sense mistake forever

Answer (score 5):

Using the Bit Data type.

"The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on.

The string values `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be converted to bit values: `TRUE` is converted to 1 and `FALSE` is converted to 0.

Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1."

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177603.aspx)

Comment: I've gone through that MSDN link but how to restrict inserting any value apart from 0 and 1 without defining any CHECK constraint on that column. Is there any trace flag or any setting available?
I observed, in MySQL it restricts such insertion throwing an error "Data Too Long"

Comment: why don't you put this restriction in place in your application before values are being inserted into the database? or is this not an option?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a CHECK constraint?

Comment: A `CHECK` constraint won't help here. By the time such a constraint is applied, the implicit or explicit conversion to `bit` has already occurred, and so all values that the `CHECK` constraint might observe are either 0 or 1.

Comment: I think you've not understood what I asked. I can't declare a CHECK constraint on all tables. I need to know whether this is a bug in SQL Server and is there any trace flag to restrict the user from inserting any value apart from 0 or 1. It means I should get an error like "Data Too Long" or "Data Overflow" if I insert any value apart from 0 and 1.

Comment: @YashwanthAluru - it's not a *bug*. It's documented behaviour. You have to remember that T-SQL is old, to the point that "back in the day" in other languages also it was thought to be sensible to treat 0 as false and "any non-zero value" as true. So they maintain the behaviour for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Seems if you want that functionality you should use a tinyint with a check constraint instead.